# Show New Comment Count in View

Tags: views, 8, theming, hooks

If you use the messaging system in Drupal.org, you have noticed that if you go to your messages, there may be a link that says New Message next to the thread.

We have Q&A section where people ask questions and others leave comments.

What is the proper field to add in views that will show "New Message" or "X new messages". The notification will be to the login user only. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want **new comments**

[image]